# Adobe Flashplayer plugin - when will this be upgraded on Ubuntu?

Tags: flash, adobe

When trying to access live broadcast of a football match Adobe Flashplayer crashes and it appears to be caused by the fact that Ubuntu does not support the latest version of Adobe Flashplayer plugin. Is there a way in which I can do this? Or what is the alternative?

Answer (score 3):

I will neither talk about the security issues related to using proprietary plugins (that recently proved being faulty in many ways), nor about the ethical implications in it.
I will just talk about the story, which is not as simple as you write it, and Ubuntu is completely unrelated to it.

There are 3 players in the game. Mozilla, Google and Adobe.

Adobe at some points decides that it will not update the Flash NPAPI plugin for Linux, for reasons that no one else knows, nor has to know.
They are a private company, they choose what to develop and what not. Fine.

Google at some point starts developing a new way to integrate plugins in a browser, called [PPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#PPAPI) and abandon after some time the old technology [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI), developed by Netscape.

Together with what above, this implies also that on Android you could not play Flash contents anymore.
This is a bit less fine than before and it piss off a lot of users, coders and companies.

At some point in history Adobe and Google start talking and they find a way to develop and mantain a PPAPI version of the latest Flash plugin, that will be packaged directly by Google and embedded into Chrome.

Now, Mozilla [can't/won't use PPAPI technology in Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:Pepper). This, with what is above, implies that the latest Flash plugin from Adobe/Google won't work in Firefox. Fine, there is alwasy the 5-years-old NPAPI plugin from Adobe that we can use.
Unfortunately this does not include the latest features and it is block by more and more websites everyday (note that Adobe claims that it is secure, as they still provide security updates).

So the question now. Is there another browser, apart from Google Chrome, that works on Linux and can take advantage of the latest PPAPI proprietary Flash plugin?
Yes, any browser that supports PPAPI techonology.
Like? For example the ([non completely free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Licensing)) Chromium-browser, on which Google Chrome is based.

Now, how to take advantage of this latest PPAPI plugin in Chromium?
[Following the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash).